# Line/Paths intersecting

Tags: android, path, vector-graphics

I'm making a simple eraser tool for a vector based drawing program.
[image: example]

I save my paths in a `List` as `android.graphics.Path` and then draw them in a loop onto a canvas with `canvas.drawPath(path, paint)`. In this example the red line is the eraser and the green line should be erased.

I have tried to convert the `Paths` into `Regions` and calling `redRegion.op(greenRegion, Region.OP.INTERSECT)`. I think the issue is that the Paths don't have a surface area, because the Paint is not applied yet, they are just simple lines.

I'm building for API lvl 15.

Answer (score 0):

If your background is always white your could just make the "Eraser" a path that is white. Then it will make it seem like the other lines are being erased.

Edit:

Maybe you could query all the points that are used to draw your paths in your on touch events and create a custom class to encapsulate that. Then have a method that is like:

```
//other code....
    MyCustomClass class = new MyCustomClass();

    if(class.contains(float x, float y)) {
      //...erase line
    } 
//other code
```

the MyCustomClass

```
public class MyCustomClass {

  private List<PathPoints> pathPoints;

  public MyCustomClass(List<PathPoints> points) {
   this.pathPoints = points;
  }

  public boolen contains(float x, float y) {

    for(PathPoint point: pathPoints) {
      if(x == point.getX() && y == point.getY()) {
        return true;
      } 
      return false; 

    }
  } 

}
```

and the path points class

```
public class PathPoint {

  private float x;
  private float y;
  private int movementType;

  public void setX(float x) {
  this.x = x;
} 

//..all the other getters and setters. 

}
```

then in your onTouch event add a new PathPoint to a list of path ponits for each path that is draw. Only create a new path point in Action.UP (user has stopped drawing).

EDIT 2: Ok so here's another idea. Why don't you create your own custom path class and then add all this logic into that class. So as you're drawing the path you can just add path points to the path. Then add a method "contains()" to your custom path class. That way it will contain every point that is on the path, whether it is move to, line to, quad to or whatever. So something like this:

```
public class MyPath extends Path {

    private List<PathPoint> points;

    public MyPath(List<PathPoints> pathPoints) {
        this.points = pathPoints;
    }

    public void addPathPoint(PathPoint pathPoint) {
        if(points != null) {
            points.add(pathPoint);
        }
    }

    public boolean contains(float x, float y) {
        for(PathPoint pathPoint: points) {
            if(pathPoint.getX() == x && pathPoint.getY() == y) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

The drawing part of it should work fine still because you're not touching it. Let me know if this works.

Comment: The line should be deleted completely.

Comment: So if a line is touched it should be gone completely?

Comment: Nope. PathPoint only saves the cornerpoints/controlpoints. In contains it only checks for those and all points in between will not match.

Comment: Oh yes, thats right. Youll need to add a new path point in every event then but then youd need to somehow know which pathpoints are for which path...

Comment: The problem with the code is that the points from the eraser are never going to be exactly equal to the controlpoints used to draw the lines. A simple equals will not cut it, you have to calculate the distance and if it less than half of the width of the eraser plus half the width of the line it definetely intersects. I have implemented a similar solution by calculating points on my paths using PathMeasure. The issue is that it performs absolutely horribly, it takes several seconds with hundreds of paths.